# Angular2: Multiple router-outlet in Child Componet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am creating ng2 version of scotch.io 's [angular-ui-router tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router).
I am able to achieve the basic navigation for `home` and `about` page. In `home` I am able to create navigation for children i.e. `list` and `paragraph`. I am stuck with `about` page. I am able to navigate to about page but I am not able to render the child `component` of `about` in their corresponding outlets. This is what I am doing:

**about.component.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>The About Page</h1>
    <p>This page demonstrates <span class="text-danger">multiple</span> and <span class="text-danger">named</span> views.</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <router-outlet name="aboutOne"></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="aboutTwo"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

**about.routes.ts**

```
export const aboutRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'about',
                outlet: 'aboutOne',
                component: AboutOneComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'about',
                outlet: 'aboutTwo',
                component: AboutTwoComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

**about-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { aboutRoutes } from './about.routes';
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(aboutRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AboutRoutingModule {

}
```

I don't know what I am missing. The about page is being rendered but it's not rendering it's child component also there's no error in the console. Here's the complete [github repo](https://github.com/hk-skit/angular2routing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After playing with named `<router-outlet>`, I figured out that. I was not giving the proper paths. Since both of my component should be rendered in their corresponding outlets when user lands into the `about` page. There's not relative url/path for both. They are default children of `about`. So I updated my `path:'about'` to `path:''`. And it started working. Hope this will be helpful to someone.

**about.routes.ts**

```
export const aboutRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                outlet: 'aboutOne',
                component: AboutOneComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: '',
                outlet: 'aboutTwo',
                component: AboutTwoComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

@Pradeep Thanks for highlighting the `path` issue.

Comment: Thank you. I spend whole day to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Hey @hitesh most probably the error is in routing of about component, you have used same name of path in for both components as well as parent one please change this and try it like this

```
export const aboutRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'aboutOne',
                outlet: 'aboutOne',
                component: AboutOneComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'aboutTwo',
                outlet: 'aboutTwo',
                component: AboutTwoComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Might be the case angular will try to load component on the basis of URL whihc is found `about` in every case so child component may not render in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The things is that both `aboutOne` and `aboutTwo` are not routes but they are views as you can see the scotch.io tutorial. http://embed.plnkr.co/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7/preview  It simply has two `ui-view` and the routes templates are falling into these views. I want to do something similar using router-outlet. That my component goes into the corresponding outlet in the same route

Comment: will you please recreate your problem on some plunker ??

Comment: I have the repo code. https://github.com/hk-skit/angular2routing You can look into it. I have created the repo using angular-cli. So moving it to plunkr will be time consuming.

Comment: ohh , sorry bro even i dont have much time to make your repo run, but your provided plunker seems from angular1.x http://embed.plnkr.co/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7/preview

Comment: Yeah. I want to create angular2 version of the same. As you can see in app.js, the `about` state. how can we achieve the same using angular 2?

Comment: I Dont have much idea about state in angular1.x but yes in angular2 routing will run using path only we have to match path for any component to open and yes named outlet's also exists in angular2.

Comment: Cool. I delve about outlets and try to figure out.